# Missing java.util.HashMap

Tags: blackberry, hashmap, java

Is there any reason that I would be missing the java.util.HashMap package? I have java.util.Hashtable, but no HashMap...

I have the most up to date JDK and JRE...

Thanks!

Comment: what error do you get and what's the code exactly?

Comment: how do you know it's missing?

Comment: java.util.HashMap is a class, not a package.

Comment: I receive the following (in Eclipse): "The import java.util.HashMap cannot be resolved", and that's when I add "import java.util.HashMap"

Comment: Try recompiling it.  Don't just add something and save it.  Force a rebuild by clicking on the file and selecting compile file or click on the project and select clean and rebuild.

Comment: I tried recompiling it, and there is no change. I think that it is missing a lot of things, like ArrayList, too...

Comment: I also see an error that the build path is incomplete, and that it cannot find the class file for java.util.Map

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow - that's weird! Could it be that your working on a mobile app like development for a Blackberry? The [Blackberry Java](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.1api/index.html) does have a `java.util.Hashtable` but no `java.util.HashMap`... This would be a perfect match for your problem ;)

**Edit**

If you want to develop Blackberry applications, then you **have** to use the 'Blackberry Java', because that is the Java that is installed on the mobile. Otherwise just install a fresh eclipse on your machine. You can have as many eclipse IDE's on your machine as you like. They do not interfere.

Comment: That is precisely what I am doing! I guess I should have mentioned that. The Blackberry plugin installed Eclipse for me. Instead, should I install Eclipse first, and then specify (in the plugin installation) an existing Eclipse installation?

Comment: Bingo :-)) Yes, we usually assume SUN Java SDK or something else when we just read java

Comment: A fresh eclipse? I would just add another workspace and pick the desired one during startup.

Comment: I think there's a solution for beginners and for pros - and I don't know the setup of this special 'Blackberry-eclipse'.

Answer (score 4):

Blackberry has a different implementation for HashMap , it has a class called multimap under net.rim.device.api.util.MultiMap which is similar to HashMap.

It can be used to do similar task as HashMap. The documenation can be found http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/MultiMap.html>here.

Supported since API 4.3.0

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry devices use a subset of the Java API called [J2ME](http://java.sun.com/javame/technology/index.jsp).  It does not have all of the features of the regular JDK, such as collections.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, is the JDK in the classpath for the project itself? Although you're eclipse instance may be pointing to the JDK, it may not be available within the project's own classpath.

As well, are you using the standard JDK? If you're using an implementation of the JDK that has a subset of the full JDK, that library may not be available.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when i install J2ME SDK 3.

I open eclipse and get error what "Eclipse The import java.util cannot be resolved"

In windows i goto environment variables and found there var CLASSPATH with value ".;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip" for me i just delete this variable and eclipse projects start work fine and J2ME also works.